# QT 3.3.8b does not connect SIGNAL to SLOT in a new class

Tags: c++, qt, class, signals, slot

I pretty much like discovering my error but this is something I can't get over.
I have created a new class by making these 2 files:

ltdocs.h:

```
#ifndef LANG_TEXT_DOCS_H
#define LANG_TEXT_DOCS_H

#include <qobject.h>
#include <qaction.h>

#include "error.h"

class TLangTextDocs  :  public QObject
{

public :

    bool saveAsNew();

public slots:

    void onSaveAsNew();


};


#endif
```

It's corresponding cpp file:

```
#include "lang_text_docs.h"

void TLangTextDocs::onSaveAsNew()
{ ERROR("haho" );
    saveAsNew();
}

bool TLangTextDocs::saveAsNew()
{
    ERROR("haho") ;
}
```

Not much, but I can't get forward before making sure the SIGNAL/SLOT works.
Here's the snippet where I would like to connect a QAction in a different file:

```
TLangTextDocs * xLangTextDocs = FLangTextsWriterDlg->langTextDocs();
if ( xLangTextDocs ) ERROR("haho xltd" );
xLangTextDocs->saveAsNew(); //for debug

TActionList xActions = FLangTextsWriterDlg->actions();
QAction * xSaveAction = xActions.action( TLangTextsWriterDlg::a_Save, TRUE ); //TRUE: Verbose
if ( ! xSaveAction ) ERROR("haho no saveaction" );

if ( ! connect( xSaveAction, SIGNAL( activated() ), xLangTextDocs, SLOT( onSaveAsNew() ) ) ) ERROR("haho not connected");
//if ( xSaveAction ) connect( xSaveAction, SIGNAL( activated() ), this, SLOT( onSaveLangText() ) );
```

FLangTextsWriterDlg was created before and when it was initialized a new TLangTextDocs was created as "FLangTextDocs = new TLangTextDocs;".
FLangTextsWriterDlg->langTextDocs() does nothing more than "return FLangTextDocs";
I get the error message "haho xltd", so the object is obviously created.
"xLangTextDocs->saveAsNew();" pulls up the error dialog correctly saying "haho".
Then the QAction * gets extracted as I get no error message.
Somehow though the connect returns FALSE and the slot does not get called. The commented connect was a previous version that worked flawlessly... it's just not what I need.

Why does that QAction's signal not connect to xLangTextDocs' slot?

Comment: QT 3.3.8b? Long term support for Qt 5.9 has been canceled this year. Qt 5.15 is the new version in long term support as well as Qt 6.2 (since recently). Did you confuse something or do you really try to use such an old Qt?

Comment: Really. That's what we use at work. Probably for some compatibility issues but I don't really know. If this is what we got then this is what we got.

Comment: When I started with Qt round about 4 years ago, it was already Qt5. According to [Wikipedia: Qt version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_version_history) Qt3.3 was released in 2004. Hence, I wonder a bit. (I always believed to stick to my written code but I wouldn't try to use a C++ compiler of 2004 or code that I wrote that time... ...except for getting some inspiration when re-writing it).

Comment: I never used Qt before Qt4 but if they are somewhat similar you forgot `Q_OBJECT` inside `TLangTextDocs`

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how that works, looks like I gotta read up on this Meta Object System or what, but thanks! Finally I can continue my work.